# Affinity fafw3511kw0 front load washer will run a full cycle empty but not with clothes in it

Tags: washing-machine

Affinity fafw3511kw0 front load washer will run a full cycle empty but not with clothes in it. With clothes it stops after about 20-25 minutes and resets back to start time. The clothes are sopping wet but no standing water in tub. I have already replaced the control board.

Comment: Some washing machines have a feature of detecting an out-of-balance loads, by various means; this sounds like this being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

First, check that the washer is *level*. Put a carpenter's level on top and adjust the screws in each corner of the bottom of the washer so that it is level bot front-to-back and side-to-side.

If leveling does not help, it might be an out-of-balance vibration issue. The machine has [spring supports (14) and a Shock absorber (30)](https://www.partselect.com/Models/FAFW3511KW0/Sections/MOTOR-TUB/?ModelID=1519669&ModelNum=FAFW3511KW0&mfgModelNum=&ManufactureID=4&Selected=HYX1YZTF&Position=4&mfg=Frigidaire&Type=Washer&Mark=4) (vibration damper), in this diagram for *PartsSelect*. With time, a spring sags or breaks, and the shock absorber loses effectiveness.

There is also a vibration sensor that detects shaking, but it might be on the main control PCB that you replaced, and is likely not at fault.

If the drum drags or scrapes against the surround, or if, when shaken, it does not quickly come to rest, it could be a spring or damper needs replacement. The parts are not expensive, but putting them in place can be difficult, particularly springs, which must be stretched to fit. Though I have replaced those on a similar machine, I do not recommend it for the inexperienced.

Buying parts, if one is not sure of the issue, just discards money. Be sure to carefully check what, if anything is broken before getting a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

If the clothes are chunky such as denim or wool then try lightening the load or mix some other clothes with them.

If its till stops with small, untangled cotton clothes, then you probably have an issues with the machine.